# Автономно работающий на хостинге .php

Tags: javascript, php

Есть хостинг [reg.ru](https://www.reg.ru/), есть сайт(пока не залит), суть в том, что есть .php файл который обновляет значение элементов в .json который лежит рядом с ним, это обновление происходит по алгоритму: к первому элементу +2, ко второму элементу +3 и к третьему элементу +7756. Как вариант было решение создать `cron` задачу, но обновление .json нужно делать каждые 5 секунд(`cron` позволяет выполнить скрипт лишь один раз за 10 минут). **Как сделать так чтобы, .php выполнялся раз за 5 секунд или сделать его автономным и кодом установить интервал на повторение?**

*P.S. после обновления значения в .josn, обновленные данные забирает javascript*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему `cron` позволяет один раз в 10 минут? От 1 минуты. `* * * * * php /путь_к_файлу` будет выполнять каждую минуту. 
Раз в 5 секунд можно создав несколько записей в `cron`:

```
 * * * * * php myscript.php
 * * * * * sleep 5 && php myscript.php
 * * * * * sleep 10 && php myscript.php
 * * * * * sleep 15 && php myscript.php
 * * * * * sleep 20 && php myscript.php
 * * * * * sleep 25 && php myscript.php
 * * * * * sleep 30 && php myscript.php
 * * * * * sleep 35 && php myscript.php
 * * * * * sleep 40 && php myscript.php
 * * * * * sleep 45 && php myscript.php
 * * * * * sleep 50 && php myscript.php
 * * * * * sleep 55 && php myscript.php
```

Раз в 5 секунд можно ещё таким способом

```
#!/bin/sh

while true; do
/usr/bin/php /путь_к_файлу "cron"
sleep 5
done
```

или в самом скрипте :

```
 while( true ) {

        // function();

        sleep( 5 );

    }
```

Ешё как вариант - запускать через `js+ajax` используя `setinterval`

Дополнительно можно использовать демоны на сервере для запуска.

Или уж совсем экзотично

```
<?php
...
echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"Refresh\" CONTENT=\"5; URL=название_файла\">"
?>
```

Comment: про подход с `while( true)`, т. е. если я один раз запущу с cron этот .php, то он будет выполняться бесконечно?

Comment: @MidNightElf Верно. `While(true)` будет выполнять скрипт, пока условия в скрипте выполняются.

Comment: а, из-за этого могут возникнуть проблемы? переполнение например? есть у таким образом выполняемого скрипта что то вроде мусорника куда он сбрасывает ненужное?

Comment: @MidNightElf Переполнение чего? Нет, он просто выполняет скрипт, пока код внутри него выполняется. Не совсем понимаю, что подразумеваете под "ненужным".

Comment: Еще интересен последний способ, экзотичный. Этот php фрагмент вставляется в конец моего .php файла который надо запускать и когда он закончит выполнять код сверху, то подождет 5 секунд и снова сам себя запустит?

Comment: @MidNightElf Да, всё верно. )

Comment: Странно, попробовал ваш экзотичный способ, чет не робит, так выглядит php https://imgur.com/B5rxrqC

Comment: @MidNightElf Указывайте путь к самому файлу, а не ссылку. Вот пример: `<?php

echo 'sdklfjlksdjf';

echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"Refresh\" CONTENT=\"5; URL=help1.php\">"
?>` в случае, если текущий файл называется `help1.php`

Comment: Аа, я тоже так подумал, но потом увидел, что написано "адрес файла" вот я и подумал...

Comment: @MidNightElf Да, Вы правы, непонятно написал - изменил.

Comment: Извините что так трачу ваше время, вы уверены что этот метод работает? Просто у меня не получается. Вот эта строка, все остальное как на картинке `echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"Refresh\" CONTENT=\"5; URL=counterupdate.php\">";`

Comment: @MidNightElf Да, точно работает - протестировал. Попробуйте скопировать то, что я писал в комментарии полностью и добавить в тестовый файл новый. Увидите, что происходит перезагрузка страницы и файл запускается снова.

Comment: @MidNightElf Вот так будет нагляднее `<?php

echo date("h:m:s");

echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"Refresh\" CONTENT=\"5; URL=help1.php\">"
?>
`

Comment: Действительно если добавить эту строку в index.php, она перезагружается. Но если добавить в файл `countervalues.php` (так называется файл который должен выполняться каждые 5 секунл) ничего не происходит. Ксати, этот файл просто написан и лежит в папке на хостинге, я повесил его к крон задачу на 10 минут. Прошло уже 14 минут, по идее он должен был уже запуститься один раз и выполняться, но он этого не делает

Comment: @MidNightElf Покажите как прописали в крон задачу. Файл должен выполняться, если добавлена корректная запись. Протестировано несколько раз. Тоже самое касается и экзотического варианта. Явно в самом файле какая-то ошибка.

Comment: ок, можете сказать или показать как вы протестировали. Поскольку пхп скрипт рабочий, протестировано, а крон задача она не записывается, просто выбираешь промежуток времени и файл

Comment: @MidNightElf покажите Вашу задачу в кроне. Скорее всего Вы просто не корректно сделали запись. 99%. Или создайте новый вопрос. Ответ дан и каждый из вариантов полностью рабочий.

Comment: https://imgur.com/h8xAmXA так выглядит заданная крон задача, и она выполняется, т.е. каждые 2 минуты происходит обновление и значения счетчиков меняется. Но не меняется после 5 секунд. А ваш экзотичный метод несомненно работает, он обновляет страницу `index.php` если вставить строку туда. Но почему то он не работает с этим скриптом, может ли это быть потому что такое выполнение блокирует сам хост?