# Циклическая команда UPDATE с интервалом

Tags: php, mysql

как мне реализовать циклическую команду UPDATE для базы mysql при условии, что скрипт будет работать без участия блаузера.
Идея в том, чтобы запись в базе mysql редактировалась с интервалом к примеру 20сек.автономно и учитывая алгоритм для новых данных.

Comment: Если достаточно обновлений раз в минуту, то через cron. Если нет, то делаете бесконечный цикл и нужную паузу

Comment: @Shihzamanapp Вам необходимо сделать выполняемый скрипт записи. Варианты запуска скрипта каждые n секунд можете посмотреть тут - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1080219/%d0%90%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3%d0%b5-php/1080229#1080229

Answer (score 0):

Советую почитать про [php демон](https://habr.com/ru/post/134620/). Как вариант можно использовать его для выполнения определенной логики. Зачастую, демонов используют для реализации шаблона проектирования "наблюдатель", который смотрит в базу с определенным интервалом и что-то делает. Например, демон, который опрашивает всех подключенных пользователей и расставляет статусы.

Как другой вариант можно использовать самописный скрипт, который будет вызываться через [cron с определенным интервалом](https://mblogm.ru/blog/cron-for-php-scripts/).